# Python BeautifulSoup, Request, doens't scrape the full page

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

I am trying to scrape a website for some links. The problem is that the links are hidden in the body of the code and my code doesn't wanna scrape that part.

This is what is looks like:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/vGDvc.png

and this is what I need: https://i.stack.imgur.com/lNqPZ.png

BeautifulSoup just doenst show me those hrefs in the page's body.

Please help, thank you.

Comment: Without any proof to the contrary, yes it does.

Answer (score 1):

all content are passing to the BeautifulSoup no matter they are visible or not!
just find the target xpath or any selector

Comment: I am printing out the "soup" so the full unfilereted content and in word i am searching for the https, it is not in the soup.

Comment: @BalazsL - I don't know what you mean by "printing out".  Your first screenshot seems to have much of the content collapsed down visually by folding.  I'm pretty sure that the view you show says nothing about what's actually there.  I also don't understand what you mean by "BS just doesn't show me".  BS isn't a visual tool...it's a HTML parsing library.  I can't think what you could mean by it showing something to you.  I'm quite familiar with BS.  The bottom line is...if what you're looking for comes back in the response to the HTTP query you're sending, BS will have access to it.